# How do I use StringBuilder in Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, stringbuilder

I'm using stringbuilder in a method to print out a representation of the data that I stored in an array. So the code looks like this:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder(numRows * (num(ols + 1)));
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
            if (x[i][j] == ('*')){
                System.out.print('*');
            } else {
                System.out.print(' ');
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

The problem is my compiler can't find the symbol ols on the line

```
StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder(numRows*(num(ols+1)));
```

I've never used StringBuilder before so what I'm wondering is how do I make this work and do I even need StringBuilder because all I'm trying to do is print out a representation of the data that I've stored in an array.

Comment: Where did you expect `ols` to be defined?  What is it even supposed to mean?

Comment: *"The problem is my compiler can't find the symbol `ols` on the line"* - Apparently, neither can we

Comment: That said, passing an argument to the `StringBuilder` constructor is an optimization and removing it should keep the program working.  (Not that you use it later on in the code, which is itself probably a sign of a problem.)

Comment: If all you want to do is print the data in an array, just use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo));`.

Comment: Maybe try changing `num(ols` to `numCols` ?

Comment: ok that fixes the ols problem but now my compiler is saying it expects a return statement. I was thinking of saying return S however it says that's not a proper return type. So what's going on with that?

Comment: For that we'll have to see more of the code.  Can you edit your question with the rest of the method?

Comment: It is the entire method with the line  public String toString() at the top

Comment: Okay, you're going to want to actually use the StringBuilder to build the string. And then you can return `S.toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the body of the for loop, I'm guessing

```
StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder(numRows*(num(ols+1)));
```

Should be

```
StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder(numRows*(numCols+1));
```

This may not be the final string you are looking to build, but here's an example of using the StringBuilder (I changed the name from `S` to `sb` because it's more usual to use lowercase letters for variable names, saving uppercase for class names and constants.)

```
class Foo {
    int numRows = 3;
    int numCols = 2;
    char[][] x = new char[][] { { 'a', '*' }, { 'x', 'y' }, { '*', '#' } };

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(numRows * (numCols + 1));
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
                if (x[i][j] == ('*')) {
                    sb.append('*');
                    System.out.print('*');
                } else {
                    sb.append(' ');
                    System.out.print(' ');
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That works however now I have another problem where the method wants a return statement however I'm not sure what to return. I can't return S because stringbuilder cannot be converted to a string.